# How do you insert / find rows related by foreign keys from different tables using Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I think I've done enough research on this subject and I've only got a headache.

**Here is what I have done and understood:** I have restructured my MySQL database so that I will keep my user's data in different tables, I am using foreign keys. Until now I only concluded that **foreign keys are only used for consistency and control** and they do not automatize or do anything else (for example, to insert data about the same user in two tables I need to use two separate insert statements and the foreign key will not help to make this different or automatic in some way).

**Fine. Here is what I want to do:** I want to use Sequelize to insert, update and retrieve data altogether from all the related tables at once and I have absolutely no idea on how to do that. For example, if a user registers, I want to be able to insert the data in the table "A" containing some user information and in the same task insert in the table B some other data (like the user's settings in the dedicated table or whatever). Same with retrievals, I want to be able to get an object (or array) with all the related data from different tables fitting in the criteria I want to find by.

Sequelize documentation covers the things in a way that every thing depends on the previous one, and Sequelize is pretty bloated with a lot of stuff I do not need. I do not want to use .sync(). I do not want to use migrations. I have the structure of my database created already and I want Sequelize to attach to it.

**Is it possible insert and retrieve several rows related at the same time and getting / using a single Sequelize command / object? How?**

Again, by "related data" I mean data "linked" by sharing the same foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible insert and retrieve several rows related at the same
>   time and getting / using a single Sequelize command / object? How?

Yes. What you need is [eager loading](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#eager-loading).

Look at the following example

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const Address = sequelize.define('add', {
  address: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const Designation = sequelize.define('designation', {
  designation: Sequelize.STRING,
});

User.hasOne(Address);
User.hasMany(Designation);

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => User.create({
    username: 'test123',
    add: {
      address: 'this is dummy address'
    },
    designations: [
      { designation: 'designation1' },
      { designation: 'designation2' },
    ],
  }, { include: [Address, Designation] }))
  .then(user => {
    User.findAll({
      include: [Address, Designation],
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
```

In `console.log`, you will get all the data with all its associated models that you want to include in the query

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted! :) Now I am going to fight to solve the problems that Sequelize is causing me by pluralizing / singularizing names without any apparent sense.